# Why would someone want deterministic deconstruction of classes?

Tags: class, computer-science

I was reading a bit about D language and come up with this comparison with C++.

http://dlang.org/cpptod.html#raii

At the end of the section possibility of deterministic deconstruction of classes is mentioned, and I'm unsure when would I want to apply something like that. Examples welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collectors are rather slow - they may release a huge memory block much later than corresponding variable went out of scope.
For example, data contained in variables of CLOB datatype in Oracle DBMS is recommended to be released manually (by calling special procedure) despite of presence of automatic garbage collector in PL/SQL language.